# Appending new lists to key in double for loop

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means, pca

I am doing KMeans clustering where I also do Principal Component Analysis beforehand. I am trying to look for nice useable clusters. For this, I want to automatically look which value for number of clusters k gives me the best silhouette score for every p.

In my double for loop, I am applying PCA with a number of principal components in the first for loop and then applying a number of k in the second nested for loop. Ultimately, I want a dictionary that shows the number of k and the silhouette score for every p. This is my current function:

```
def optimal_clust(df_scaled, minPCA, maxPCA, minClust, maxClust):
    p = 'Number of PCs'
    k = 'Number of k'
    silhouette = 'Silhouette score'
    clustdict = {p :[k, silhouette]}
    for p in range(minPCA, maxPCA):
        pca = PCA(n_components = p)
        df_pca = pca.fit_transform(df_scaled)
        for k in range(minClust, maxClust+1):
            kmeans_labels = KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state = 0).fit_predict(df_pca)
            silhouette = silhouette_score(df_pca, kmeans_labels)
            clustdict[p] = []
            clustdict[p].append([k, silhouette])

    return clustdict

print(optimal_clust(df_scaled, minPCA, maxPCA, minClust, maxClust))
```

This only gives me a dictionary for the value of maxClust+1 for every p, which is 5. The output is as follows:

```
{'Number of PCs': ['Number of k', 'Silhouette score'], 1: [[5, 0.5242417773868049]], 2: [[5, 0.3274181367447551]], 3: [[5, 0.267904945833515]], 4: [[5, 0.22204357317276344]], 5: [[5, 0.1917496386757678]], 6: [[5, 0.16193197736304277]], 7: [[5, 0.14803935348320568]]}
```

How can I fix this such that it gives me the full result in a dict? When I choose to print it instead of storing it in a dictionary, it does give me everything. Thank you.

Comment: are you sure maxPCA is bigger than 2?

Comment: @Vincenzo Lavorini yes, it's set to the number of columns of the dataframe I use for my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

So, I fiddled around with defeaultdict and found the solution luckily:

```
def optimal_clust(df_scaled, minPCA, maxPCA, minClust, maxClust):
    clustdict = defaultdict(list)
    for p in range(minPCA, maxPCA):
        pca = PCA(n_components = p)
        df_pca = pca.fit_transform(df_scaled)
        for k in range(minClust, maxClust+1):
            kmeans_labels = KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state = 0).fit_predict(df_pca)
            silhouette = silhouette_score(df_pca, kmeans_labels)
            clustdict[p].append([k, silhouette])
    return clustdict

print(optimal_clust(df_scaled, minPCA, maxPCA, minClust, maxClust))
```

This gave me:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [[2, 0.5607920149433261], [3, 0.5399029168499861], [4, 0.524472082127441], [5, 0.5242417773868053]], 2: [[2, 0.38034477108342357], [3, 0.33609893188462264], [4, 0.3569575287929635], [5, 0.3274181367447551]], 3: [[2, 0.3140852723397097], [3, 0.2562260449736865], [4, 0.2617649481080593], [5, 0.26790494583351326]], 4: [[2, 0.27246318004094644], [3, 0.2132773501296108], [4, 0.21770628900170838], [5, 0.2220435731727633]], 5: [[2, 0.24158506265896904], [3, 0.17760388468121172], [4, 0.18279294131764684], [5, 0.1917496386757677]], 6: [[2, 0.21697223677862587], [3, 0.15338479734413427], [4, 0.17366692394358288], [5, 0.16193197736304285]], 7: [[2, 0.2011962666408952], [3, 0.1412926150132645], [4, 0.15261307055636883], [5, 0.14803935348320568]]})
```

Which is exactly what I want.